# How fast is simplex method to solve tsp?

Tags: linear-programming

How fast is simplex method compared with brute-force or any other algorithm to solve a ts problem?

Comment: For more answers, please try: http://www.or-exchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't model a TS problem with a "pure" LP problem (with continuous variables). You can use an integer-programming formulation, wich will use the simplex method at each node of a research tree (branch and bound or branch and cut method). It will work for small problems, but it is slow because the problem is hard: with one binary variable for each edge for instance, you need a lot of constraints to model the fact that the path is a cycle.

Brute-force is intractable (the problem is exponential), do not even try it unless you have a **very** small problem. Use the MIP formulation, even for small problems.

For big problems, you should use some kind of heuristic (I think simulated annealing give good results on this one), or a "smart" modelization of you problem (column generation for instance) if you want an exact solution.

Comment: I didn't understand much but why is simplex method slow? I.e. can I use branch-and-bound with mip formulation?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use a branch-and-bound method. It will be slow for large input because TS is a hard problem, and your MIP formulation will have a lot of constraints (or a lot of variables): there is no "simple and fast" method.

Comment: However, I was pointing out that simplex and branch-and-bound are different algorithms: the simplex is used for continuous linear problems, and is (often) used in the relaxations at each node of the branch-and-bound research tree. You can't use **directly** the simplex method to solve a MIP.

Comment: If you have glpk, there is an implementation in the examples (I think it is called "tspsol", but I can't check right now).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you explain what means integer problem? Simplex needs an additional constraint?

Comment: An integer problem is a problem with integer (or binary) variables. In particular, this means that the set of admissible solutions is not a convex polyedra: you can't use the simplex method at all (even if you "add additional constraints"). See the wikipedia article on linear programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming, in particular the section 11 (Integer unknowns).

Comment: Is this because of triangle inequality? Why is LP and ILP is different? So simplex method doesn't apply to tsp?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but I believe that a result of Yannakakis says that you cannot model a TSP as a linear program with a polynomial number of constraints. So technically you could model TSP with only continuous variables, but the formulation will be prohibitively large. A consequence of this result is that you could not prove P=NP by finding a linear programming formulation of a TSP (which many have claimed to do).

Comment: @raoulcousins That's interesting, I didn't know about that (although I doubt it could be usefull from a 'practical' point of view). Do you have a reference about this? Is the original article "A Convex Relaxation for the asymmetric TSP" (ACM-SIAM 1999), with S. Vempala?

Comment: Sorry I meant to include some reference.
Honestly this isn't my area. I work on models and algorithms for vehicle routing problems, and a result like this is a bit far afield, so my comment wasn't exactly correct. It looks like the question was posed by Yannakakis but the result is by others. http://spokutta.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/1311/